# Android Studio add tests for newly added methods

Tags: java, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-testing

My target is to add tests for newly added methods in Android Studio. For example I have class with three methods that already has tests. I add new two methods. How can Android studio generate (add) test only for newly added tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Put your cursor on any ***public*** mehtod's name inside that class.
- See the yellow bulb on the left hand side and open the bulb options.
- Select ***Generate missed test methods***.

[image]

- You can see the list of ***uncovered public methods*** and you can go forward and auto-generate your unit test templates for each of them. :))

[image]